# How to properly group array in XML Serialization using Symfony Serializer

Tags: symfony

I have a project running on symfony 4.4 right now, which needs to return data as XML in a few endpoints.

So I've been trying for a bit to serialize an entity containing an array of objects from another entity, like this

```
public class Ticket {
    private string $uuid;

    /** @var Product[]|array $products **/
    private array $products;
    
}
```

And the product class:

```
public class Product {
    private string $uuid;
    private DateTime $startDate;
    *... getters and setters...*
}
```

I want the response to be something like this:

```
<ticket>
    <uuid>1234567890</uuid>
    <products>
        <product>
            <uuid>PROD_CAM_1</uuid>
            <startDate>2020-01-04</startDate>
        </product>
        <product>
            <uuid>PROD_CAP_2</uuid>
            <startDate>2019-04-21</startDate>
        </product>
     </products>
</ticket>
```

But I am instead getting:

```
<ticket>
    <uuid>1234567890</uuid>
    <product>
        <uuid>PROD_CAM_1</uuid>
        <startDate>2020-01-04</startDate>
    </product>
    <product>
        <uuid>PROD_CAP_2</uuid>
        <startDate>2019-04-21</startDate>
    </product>
</ticket>
```

My serializer configuration is nothing special, the only thing I have specified in my services.yaml is,in the datetime context:

```
    Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer:
    arguments:
        $defaultContext:
            datetime_format: 'Y-m-d'
```

And I simply inject the serializer service to my controller, and do the following to convert to xml:

```
$this->serializer->serialize($data,'xml',['xml_encoding' => 'utf-8']);
```

where $data is an array of Ticket

What am I missing? The symfony docs are not helping much.

Answer (score 0):

So here is one solution.

I encapsulated the array on a Products class, so the entities are left as:

```
public class Ticket {
    private string $uuid;

    /** @var Products $products **/
    private Products $products;
}
```

The new Products class is left as:

```
class Products
{
    /**
     * @var array $products
     * @SerializedName("product")
     */
    private array $products = [];

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProducts(): array
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $products
     */
    public function setProducts(array $products): void
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): void
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }
}
```

Everything else stays the same, this outputs the desired XML structure.